# Is a language which terminates in a given amount of real-time still Turing complete for all finite problems?

Tags: architecture, turing-completeness

Background: this is a continuation of [this question here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/420398/is-a-language-which-terminates-in-a-given-amount-of-real-time-still-turing-compl), further expanding the thought experiment.

In short, you have a magic calculation machine which has the following properties.
The machine is:

- Fast. The rigid definition is that the processor frequency can be arbitrarily high (though not infinite).
- Finite. (**NEW**) Any program that runs on this processor has a fixed, finite input and output size. If the program tries to output more information than it's pre-determined output size, the machine immediately exits. It is not possible to alter these values.
- Frugal. This means that the output of the machine is strictly the data that is outputted. This means that the state of the machine is not an output, and a program that loops infinitely without printing anything has the same output as a program that exits immediately.  Expanding on the *finite* quality of our machine, this means that both of the previous examples are equivalent to any program which has a pre-determined output size of 0.
- Fleeting. The processor has a pre-determined time of execution. This time can be arbitrarily high, but not infinite.

#### The question:

Given that the processor IS Turing complete with only the [fast] quality, is the processor with the other limitations also Turing complete?

---

#### I should note that a language is considered Turing complete if:

It can solve every problem that another Turing complete language can, OR
It can solve every problem that a Turing machine can solve.

#### The following should not necessarily exclude a program form Turing completeness:

The program cannot solve every problem that a Turing machine can solve *in the same way*.

---

Further more:

Does the halting problem occur for any program in this processor?

Comment: wonder what's the point re-posting [your own previously asked question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/420398/is-a-language-which-terminates-in-a-given-amount-of-real-time-still-turing-compl)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Is a language which terminates in a given amount of real-time still Turing complete?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/420398/is-a-language-which-terminates-in-a-given-amount-of-real-time-still-turing-compl) by the same OP.

Comment: You only need one counter-example.  My counter-example is a Turing machine with more memory and longer execution time than yours.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Note the new *finite* limitation

Comment: Yes.  My finite is bigger than your finite.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that has nothing to do with this being a duplication.

Comment: What duplication?  My Turing machine can solve arbitrarily more complex problems because it has more memory and computing capacity than yours.

Comment: @RobertHarvey right, So a clarification on this example, my computation machine has memory equal to your turing machine's memory +1. same with computing power.

Comment: But now you're in an infinite progression, because I can always do the same to my Turing machine.

Comment: @RobertHarvey huh, guess the example is a stalemate.

Comment: Eh, it's a specious argument anyway.  No actual machine is infinitely large, so in practical terms Turing completeness is defined by whether a programming language  has conditional branching and the ability to change an arbitrary amount of memory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness

Comment: Your focus on CPU and memory indicate some misconceptions about what Turing machines are: they are primarily a theoretical tool to prove properties regarding the complexity of computations, and whether certain decision problems are decidable. Your modification is interesting but doesn't seem to relate actual Turing machines, e.g. you limit output size instead of tape size or number of steps. Maybe [cs.se] would be a better place to ask questions about Turing machines.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Here's a simple example: consider a Turing machine which computes the series of prime numbers.

For *any arbitrarily large* limit you choose for your Tuskiomi Machine, there is a finite series of prime numbers one larger that it cannot compute but a Turing Machine can.

So, you say "Then I just add more resources to my Tuskiomi Machine so that it can compute one more prime number!" But then there is still the problem that your Machine cannot compute *two* more prime numbers.

So, you say "Then I just add more resources to my Tuskiomi Machine so that it can compute a googol more prime numbers!" But then there is still the problem that your Machine cannot compute a googol *plus one* more prime numbers.

> Does the halting problem occur for any program in this processor?

The Halting Problem says that there cannot be a program `H(p, i)` which decides whether program `p` will halt for input `i`.

Obviously, this problem does not exist for your Tuskiomi Machine, because I can trivially write program `H`:

```
def H(p, i):
    return true;
```

Therefore, the Halting Problem is trivial.

Comment: See the comments on the question for why this is falsidical, also see the *Finite* requirement that a program know how the upper limit to how much it can output before it runs.

Comment: Also see the *Fast* requirement that states that both memory and speed are arbitrarily high. in your example, my magic CPU can calculate **any** number of primes, so long as the number of primes you want is a real positive integer, or zero.

Comment: For any arbitrarily large speed you choose for your Tuskiomi Machine, there is a finite series of prime numbers one larger that it cannot compute but a Turing Machine can. So, you say "Then I just make my Tuskiomi Machine faster so that it can compute one more prime number!" But then there is still the problem that your Machine cannot compute two more prime numbers. So, you say "Then make my Tuskiomi Machine faster so that it can compute a googol more prime numbers!" But then there is still the problem that your Machine cannot compute a googol plus one more prime numbers.

Comment: When I say *any* number, I mean any number. before you say it, think it, count it, before you started typing this answer, it was, is, and forever will be possible. There is no 'add more memory'. there is enough memory. There is no 'speed up the processor' it has always been fast enough.

Comment: When you say *any* number, I say *any number plus one*.

Comment: any number + 1 ∈ any number.

Comment: It does not matter which constraints you chose for your Tuskiomi Machine. It is completely irrelevant. The Laws of Mathematics *guarantee* that *whatever* your arbitrary number is, *there still is a bigger one*. And there will *always* be *at least one* program that a Machine with higher limits than yours can compute, namely the program which prints a string of 0s on the tape that is one longer than the tape of your Tuskiomi Machine. Therefore, by the Laws of Mathematics, it is *guaranteed* that there always exists a Machine that can compute at least one programyour Tuskiomi Machine cannot.

Comment: I see what your saying, and I think the issue is that you think that the resources are static, when I wrote the question I meant to say that the resources can be changed arbitrarily between program executions

Comment: Figuring out the resource requirements of a program is provably undecidable, so you *have* to pick (or "guess") a number. Then I build a machine that is exactly identical to yours, except its guessing algorithm is "whatever you guessed plus one". By the Laws of Probability Theory, if we play this game often enough, there *will* be an instance where you guessed exactly one too low, so my machine can execute the program and yours can't.